# htaccess to make SOME php files point to a subdirectory (site/category/pagename.php)

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

There are alot of htaccess rewrite questions out there, but I couldn't find a direct solution to my problem (and I don't know how to code the htacesss to do exactly what I want).

So, the first thing I did, was get rid of any php extensions using...

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# If folder does not exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# and file exist
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f
# uncomment the below rule if you want / not optional 
# otherwise leave as is
# RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php [L]
# internally show the content of filename.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

That seemed to work.  So, if I go to www.myplace.com/pagename.php ... the url rewrites to be www.myplace.com/pagename/
This is great for MOST of the pages on my site.

But now, I have a few pages in my root directory that I want to "appear" in a sub directory. So, a page like www.myplace.com/pagesub.php would rewrite the URL as www.myplace.com/category/pagesub/

There are only 5 pages that I need to do this for, so the code doesn't need to be a global change.  I still need all the other pages to remain as regular folders (like maincat.php changing to www.myplace.com/maincat/ )

If I do the following, it just points the php page to an empty directory, and a page missing error:

```
RewriteRule    ^page1sub?$    /category/page1sub/    [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^page2sub?$    /category/page2sub/    [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^page3sub?$    /category/page3sub/    [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^page4sub?$    /category/page4sub/    [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^page5sub?$    /category/page5sub/    [NC,L]
```

Can someone show me how to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tryed something like this ?

Ex:

```
RewriteCond %{page1sub} !^/subfolder/
```

Or

```
Redirect /olddirectory http://yoursite.com/newdirectory/
```

**Edit**

I'm not sur but try something like this :

```
RewriteCond %{page1sub} ^GET\ /category/page1sub/ 
RewriteRule ^page1sub/(.*) /category/page1sub/    [NC,L]
```

Requests of /page1sub/… will be redirected externally to /category/page1sub/

Comment: The first condition doesn't work. Not sure what "subfolder" means in the condition (is it refering to the "category" folder, or to the "page1sub" folder inside of the "category" folder. And the second is a redirect (not what I'm looking for). 

Basically, if someone goes to www.mysite.com/ads.php, I want the URL to rewrite as www.mysite.com/portfolio/ads/    ...   Note: there is no /ads/ folder inside of /portfolio/, so it needs to show the content from the page www.mysite.com/ads.php

Comment: @user3412194  Subfolder was a placeholder for your page1sub my bad, i've edited my answer hope it'll help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have an index.php file within each of those sub directories?  What if you tried adding index.php at the end, or whichever file you're trying to point to

```
RewriteRule    ^page1sub?$    /category/page1sub/index.php    [NC,L]
```

**EDIT**

```
RewriteRule ^category/page1sub page1sub.php [NC,L]
```

This rule should work for you.

URL reads as "www.mysite.com/category/page1sub" and gets the content from "page1sub.php".

I tested it [here](http://nicholaswatson.ca/category/page1sub) but I won't be leaving it up forever, but you can see it working.

Comment: nope. That's the issue. The folder doesn't exists, and there no index file in it.

Comment: Ohh okay.  Well this RewriteRule is looking for the content for "myplace.com/page1sub" in the directory "category/page1sub", so if those don't exist, that's why you're getting that error page.

Where does the content for "page1sub" exist?

Comment: The page exists at ... www.sitename.com/subpage.php.

When someone goes to that url, I want the url to rewrite to www.sitename.com/category/subpage/
but I want the content to show of www.sitename.com/subpage.php

Comment: if page1sub.php is a file in your main directory, something like this should work: `RewriteRule ^category/page1sub?$ page1sub.php [NC,L]`

Comment: Maybe I need to explain what needs to happen in a clearer way...

The first part of my code allows php files to show as directory.
So, www.mysite.com/portfolio/ shows the content from www.mysite.com/portfolio.php (but the URL still reads www.mysite.com/portfolio/)
 
Similarly, www.mysite.com/advertising/ shows www.mysite.com/advertising.php (but the URL still reads www.mysite.com/advertising/)

I need www.site.com/advertising/ and www.mysite.com/advertising.php to...
A) show the content from www.mysite.com/advertising.php
B) but show the URL for www.mysite.com/portfolio/advertising/

Comment: Going to just move the files into the porfolio folder and edit the code so all the includes and images link up ... as I cant seem to get this working.

Comment: one other thing to make sure when using htaccess, is to set your base tag in the head of your html.  If you don't set that up, and you're pointing to "category/page" then any images/links will be trying to target a "category" folder, but if you set a base it'll use the base url as the target.